# Equality with CoreData string attribute not working

Tags: core-data, comparison, nsstring, equality

I can't see why this isn't working.  I have two entities, let's call them Employees and Departments.  And Departments has a String attribute called division.  This works perfectly:

```
NSLog(@"Division: %@",employee.department.division);
```

The console shows, let's say, "Worldwide Seafood".  But if I attempt a comparison with the exact same string, it fails:

```
if(employee.department.division == @"Worldwide Seafood") NSLog(@"Works in seafood!");
```

Nothing displays in the console, i.e. the comparison is not working as it should.

Make sense to anyone?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `==` to compare `NSObject` instances (in this case `NSString` instances) is a pointer comparison since Objective-C instances cannot be created on the stack. Thus, your code asks whether the `NSString` instance `employee.department.division` is the same pointer (same memory location) as a static string. This is almost certainly not the case.

You should use

```
[employee.department.division isEqualToString:@"Worldwide Seafood"]
```

More generally, you should use `-[NSObject isEqual:]` to compare object instances.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead `if ([employee.department.division isEqualToString:@"Worldwide Seafood"])...`